# Powershell with argument/parameter

Tags: powershell, macros

I need to execute a word macro using Powershell.  So far I have

```
$wd = new-object -comobject word.application 
$wd.run("PrintAll") 
$wd.quit()
```

What I would like to do is add a parameter or argument that will point to a specific folder on the network and then pass that parameter to the macro.
The macro starts like this:

```
Public sPath
Sub PrintAll()

Dim fs, f, fc, f1
 Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set f = fs.GetFolder(sPath)  ' Provide folder name where doc files are present
 Set fc = f.Files
 Dim FileList() As String
 Dim Cnt As Integer
 Cnt = 0
 Dim myDoc As Word.Document
```

I have about 70 different folder locations that I need to point to, and the goal is to only have 1 Sub (macro) in Word, but to have separate powershell scripts that point to each of the folders and pass them to the one Sub (macro).   Also I want the argument in Powershell to send the folder location to the variable sPath in the macro.

Any thoughts on how I can achieve this?

I tried

```
$wd = new-object -comobject word.application 
$wd.run('PrintAll', '\\serverX\g$\xxxxxxxx') 
$wd.quit()
```

But got error "Argument: '2' should be a System.Management.Automation.PSReference. Use [ref]."

Answer (score 1):

OK,I've tested it.

1) Please go to the VBA environment and write this code (oh god this is vb6)

```
Public Function PrintAll(arg1 As String, arg2 As String) As String

    MsgBox arg1 + arg2

    PrintAll = arg1 + arg2 

End Function
```

2) Go to PowerShell and write this code:

```
$word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$doc = $word.Documents.Open("C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\Files\A.docx")
$arg1=[ref]"Hello"
$arg2=[ref]",Buddy"
$word.Run("PrintAll",$arg1,$arg2) # The returned value is Hello,Buddy
$doc.close()
$word.quit()
```

Comment: Unfortunately I need to run the word macro because there is some formatting that needs to happen to the document before it is printed.  So I don't think this will work because it's not actually calling to the macro.

Comment: I got it, your problem is: You're passing a value in the function that isn't suitable argument for this function.